# O que é Container em POO?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, terminologia

O que é significa Container em programação orientada a objetos? Em que cenário sua utilização é melhor representada?

Comment: Pode dar um contexto? Não é um termo tão usado, pleo menos para isso.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Não vi o termo sendo usado especificamente para orientação a objetos, embora ele possa ser usado porque é algo tão fundamental que certamente é aplicado à OO.

Container é algo que contém coisas. É um local para armazenar e eventualmente transportar algumas coisas. Na programação podemos chamar de *container* todos os objetos não escalares, ou seja os objetos que são compostos por outros objetos. São estruturas de dados diversas que carregam objetos escalares ou outras estruturas, portanto pode conter outros *containers* também. Obviamente que um objeto escalar é o próprio objeto e não contém nada a não ser a si próprio.

Uma referência pode ser considerado um *container* já que o valor mesmo é outro objeto. Estruturas e classes, entre outros tipos, podem ser considerados *containers* porque possuem um ou mais dados dentro dele. Os *containers* mais óbvios são as coleções, como por exemplo o *array* que possui uma sequência de dados.

Há quem diga que ele é apenas uma estrutura dinâmica ou uma coleção de dados.

Algumas linguagens podem usar o termo de forma mais específica.

Por outro lado o termo pode ser usado em algum domínio específico, por exemplo em GUI, um controle pode ser um *container* para outros controles. Isso estaria relacionado com OOP já que quase toda GUI usa esse paradigma na sua confecção.

Importante dizer que embora *container* realmente seja usado para falar sobre injeção de dependência, esse mecanismo não é específico de OO, ele está presente em qualquer linguagem que possua algum nível de modularidade, então até mesmo as linguagens dos primórdios podem ter DI. E SOLID fala de alguns mecanismos e conceitos que devem ser usados para um bom código OO, não que esses mecanismos sejam exclusivos de OO, por isso o termo não pode ser ligado diretamente à orientação a objeto.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 5):

Container em POO geralmente é usado para se referir ao mecanismo de injeção de dependência que possui a resolução de todas as dependências. No caso é um container de injeção de dependência.
Injeção de dependência parte dos princípios do SOLID

Answer (score 1):

Em programação orientada a objetos, Container é um delimitador abstrato, ou seja, um objeto que contém outros objetos que podem ser incluídos ou removidos dinamicamente (durante o tempo de execução), diferentemente do que ocorre em uma composição onde este relacionamento é fixado durante o tempo de compilação.Cenário sua utilização é melhor representada? isso depende de que você pretende utilizar.